# Pause TFS build definition via powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to create a powershell script that pauses a TFS build definition programmatically. So far, tf.exe doesn't seem to offer any kind of functionality for that. Is there any library or api I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to pause a build?

Comment: we have some scheduled scripts that run against the build database, and I want to pause the queue while the script is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way known to do that in TFS build. Perhaps stop the build service(the build will hang up ) can be easily executed when the scheduled scripts are running.